# how to repop up the credential in terminal when using git command

Tags: git

Today I am using this command to push a branch to github in Fedora 32 terminal:

```
git push origin feature/getx
```

shows error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-open.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Then I read the blog and know that I should use token to auth with github. Then I go to github.com and generate a token. Now I need the terminal to repop up the auth so that I could enter the new token. Then I use this command to clear the old auth:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

but when I use the git command to push the `feature/getx` branch, still tell me to use token and did not popup the new auth username/token input tips. What should I do to remove the old auth that I could enable the new way to access github from terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux:

```
vim ~/.git-credentials
```

remove the github credential infomation. Rerun the push command would popup the `username/password` tips. Then type token in password input step will fix it.